# CCM add node to a cluster - ccmlib.node.TimeoutError 20 Mar 2016 05:22:05 [n1] Missing: ['127.0.1.2.* now UP']:

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ccm

I tried to add a new node in a cluster with one node already, getting the same error as landim

```
$ ccm status    
Cluster: 'cluster2'    
n1: UP    

$ ccm add n2 -i 127.0.1.2 -j 7200    

$ ccm status    
Cluster: 'cluster2'
n1: UP    
n2: DOWN (Not initialized)     

$ ccm n2 start
```

> Started: n2 with pid: 3004     Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "E:\Studies\Cassandra\ccm\ccm-master\ccm.py", line 74, in 
>   cmd.run()     File
>   "E:\Studies\Cassandra\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\cmds\node_cmds.py", line
>   206, in run     allow_root=self.options.allow_root)     File
>   "E:\Studies\Cassandra\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\node.py", line 597, in
>   start node.watch_log_for_alive(self, from_mark=mark)     File
>   "E:\Studies\Cassandra\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\node.py", line 449, in
>   watch_log_for_alive     self.watch_log_for(tofind,
>   from_mark=from_mark, timeout=timeout, filename=filename)     File
>   "E:\Studies\Cassandra\ccm\ccm-master\ccmlib\node.py", line 417, in
>   watch_log_for     raise TimeoutError(time.strftime("%d %b %Y
>   %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()) + " [" + self.name + "] Missing: " +
>   str([e.pattern for e in tofind]) + ":\n" + reads[:50] + ".....\nSee {}
>   for remainder".format(filename))
>
> **ccmlib.node.TimeoutError: 20 Mar 2016 05:22:05 [n1] Missing: ['127.0.1.2.* now UP']: .....     See system.log for remainder**

I could not see any system.log file on node2(n2) logs directory. I'm not sure how and where the above error logs!!!

**Note :** ccm populate -n works perfectly. Throws error for ccm add.

**CCM on windows 10. C* version : 3.0.3**

Comment: Did you found out what it was?

Comment: I really don't remember. Please try with the latest CCM version, it should have been fixed I guess. Or try with different C* or Python version.